# Best way to retrieve values in nested assoc-lists?

Tags: elisp, association-lists

Suppose I've got an assoc-list like this:

```
(setq x '((foo . ((bar . "llama")
                  (baz . "monkey")))))
```

And I want the value at `bar`. I can do this:

```
(assoc-default 'bar (assoc-default 'foo x))
```

But what I'd really like is something that accepts multiple keys, like

```
(assoc-multi-key 'foo 'bar x)
```

Does such a thing exist, perhaps in a package somewhere? I'm sure I could write it, but I feel like my Google-fu is just failing and I can't find it.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see any nested alists on this page. I see only ordinary, unnested alists. And it is not clear what behavior you are looking for. You say **nothing** about the behavior of `assoc-multi-key`.  Presumably it looks for matches to both of its first two arguments, but that's really all that one could suppose, from what you've said. And it clearly cannot accept more than two keys, since the alist argument (presumably `x`) is the last one, not the first one - which suggests that it is not too useful in general. Try actually **specifying** what you are looking for.

Comment: I also found the original formatting of the `setq` form in the example confusing, so I edited it to use the common dot-notation for assoc-lists.

Comment: Ah, OK. So the alist does have two levels. The question still is unclear - `assoc-multi-key` remains unspecified.

Comment: Drew: The point of `assoc-multi-key` is to look up the first key in the assoc-list. This should resolve to a new assoc-list in which we look up the next key. And so forth. Basically a short-hand for digging values out of nested assoc-lists.

Comment: @Malabarba Perhaps you could mention `let-alist` too? e.g. `(let-alist '((foo . ((bar . "llama") (baz . "monkey")))) .foo.bar)` will return `"llama"`. I guess you wrote `let-alist` after the question was asked, but it's in the spirit of the question and very worth mentionning IMO!

Comment: @YoungFrog I agree. Would you like to write that answer? I'm a little short on time now...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an option which takes the exact syntax that you asked for but in a generalized way, and is quite simple to understand. The only difference is that the `ALIST` parameter needs to come first (you could adapt it to come last, if that's important to you).

```
(defun assoc-recursive (alist &rest keys)
  "Recursively find KEYs in ALIST."
  (while keys
    (setq alist (cdr (assoc (pop keys) alist))))
  alist)
```

Then you can call it with:

```
(assoc-recursive x 'foo 'bar)
```

Comment: This is more or less what I had cooked up as well. I'm a bit surprised that this isn't part of some established library like dash or something. It seems to come up all the time when dealing with e.g. json data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more generic solution:

```
(defun assoc-multi-key (path nested-alist)
   "Find element in nested alist by path."
   (if (equal nested-alist nil)
       (error "cannot lookup in empty list"))
   (let ((key (car path))
         (remainder (cdr path)))
     (if (equal remainder nil)
         (assoc key nested-alist)
       (assoc-multi-key remainder (assoc key nested-alist)))))
```

It can take any "path" of keys.  This will return `(bar . "llama")`

```
(assoc-multi-key '(foo bar)
    '((foo (bar . "llama") (baz . "monkey"))))
```

whereas this will return `(baz . "monkey")`:

```
(assoc-multi-key '(foo bar baz)
    '((foo (bar (bozo . "llama") (baz . "monkey")))))
```

Comment: Got my first downvote for this answer.  Anyone willing to tell me why?

Comment: I disagree with the downvote since your code works (+1).  My speculation is that @Malabarba's answer is clearly more general/elegant than the other answers on offer, and so the other answers received downvotes not because they don't work, but because they're not the best one.  (That being said, I prefer the "upvote the best" option rather than "upvote the best and downvote the others" alternative.)

Comment: These two questions were downvoted because there is **one** person here who doesn't quite understand how downvotes work (and chooses to disregard the interface's request to leave a comment). It's unfortunate, but the best we all can do is upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that works with an alist nested inside another alist:

```
(defun assoc2 (outer inner alist)
  "`assoc', but for an assoc list inside an assoc list."
  (assoc inner (assoc outer alist)))

(setq alist2 '((puppies (tail . "waggly") (ears . "floppy"))
               (kitties (paws . "fuzzy")  (coat . "sleek"))))

(assoc2 'kitties 'coat alist2)       ;; => (coat . "sleek")
(cdr (assoc2 'kitties 'coat alist2)) ;; => "sleek"
```

Comment: Please people, when you down vote, leave a comment.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: I'm not offended, but am curious why.  @Malabara: there's now a meta thread on [norms on "downvote + comment"?](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/189/norms-on-downvote-comment); I'd be curious on your take.